# Where to store API url used to fetch data for Excel Table as metadata?

Tags: office-js

I'm using Office.js to fetch data from my API and populate a Table object in Excel with the returned JSON data. Populating the table correctly is all done but now I want to store the API url somewhere so that a user can click a "Refresh" button that will update data in all Table objects with their associated API url.

For a less conceptual example:
1.) User enters API url in an input box and we fetch the data from that url.
2.) A Table object in Excel is made with the data fetched from the API.
3.) A user clicks refresh and the Table object is updated with new data that was added to the API.

To complete step 3, I need to store the API url used to generate the Table object somewhere and I've no idea where to do this. I can't find any "metadata" fields in the Table class. Does anyone know where I can store arbitrary text and connect this to a Table object? I'm really stumped!

Thanks so much and please let me know if I can elaborate more

Answer (score 0):

The Table object has an [id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.table?view=office-js#id) property that is unique. You could use that as the key in a key/value pair, where value is the URL.

As for how to store the pair, you could use a custom document setting, which stores the pair in the document itself, which is probably what you want.

For more information about storage options, see [Persisting add-in state and settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings).

Comment: Hi Rick!! Thanks, this is the route I was thinking about going down. However, I noticed that when deleting Table object (TO) with id 1 then TO with id 2 becomes TO id 1, TO id 3 becomes TO id 2, etc.

So I would have to cascade delete the Settings objects corresponding to the Table object id as well with some event trigger, which seems a pretty messy solution...